# Mac OX X Captain - changed router settings IP address config from Static to unconfigured

Tags: router

Desperate situation.

Changed local router ZHONE GPON 24xx settings.

Under IP config options were static, DHCP or unconfigured.

I changed to unconfigured and saved/applied.

Unfortunately I now have no Router IP or connection and would like to fix this!

Any advice (other than you're an idiot newbie) would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Find the hardware reset button, then restore your setup from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unfortunately I now have no Router IP or connection

Reset the router by holding in the reset button.

[image]

Source [Zhone zNID 24xx Series Hardware Installation Guide](http://setuprouter.com/router/zhone/znid-gpon-2426-uk/manual-1298.pdf)